# Real time updates from mySQL database with ASP.NET SignalR

Tags: mysql, asp.net, signalr

I have looked a solution for real time updates from MS SQL Server by using SQLDependency with SignalR, but not sure if I can use it with MySQL or not.

Please guide me with a simple and efficient solution for getting updates from MySql database to my ASP.NET Application.

Comment: I've not used it but there is a `MySQLDependancy` https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDependency.html

Comment: Yes, i have seen that but its third party i guess, not of MySQL officially!

Comment: It's part of DotConnect which is available on NuGet: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/ and https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotConnect.Express.for.MySQL/8.3.422

Comment: Its dotConnect Express package does not have MySqlDependency, its in standard edition which is not free :)